# Find the number of zeroes of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

let  $f(z)=(z^2+9)(z^2+1)(z^2-1)+z^5(z^2+4)$. How many zeroes does $f$ has in $\{z|\operatorname{Re}{z}<0\}$.

I want to use the argument principle, but the integral is too long. I think I need to work with winding numbers, but I don't know how. 
Edit 1:
I know form my teacher that there should be 6 zeroes.

Comment: Typically, such problems are solved with Rouché's theorem. Do you know that?

Comment: yes I know, it didn't work ( $g=(z^2+9)(z^2+1)(z^2-1)$ and $h=z^5(z^2+4)$. g isn't always bigger then g+h

Comment: $z^5(z^2+4)$ has the higher degree, so that dominates for large $\lvert z\rvert$. Unfortunately, that has zeros on the imaginary axis, so cannot be directly used. You could split into $z^5(z^2+4) - (z^2+9)(z^2+1)$ and $(z^2+9)(z^2+1)z^2$, but it's not so obvious how many zeros the first part has in either half-plane. Usually, in such exercises, there's a trick that makes it easy, but so far I haven't seen it here.